# Why don't reference members refer the assigned variable on nested vectors? What's a proper way to declare an alternative way to access a class member?

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference, member

I would like to declare an alternative way to access a class member (an array position specifically), as in

```
class Foo {
    int a[2];
    int &a_first = a[0];
};
```

such that any access to `a_first` in a `Foo` instance is for all purposes equivalent to accessing `a[0]` of that same instance.

The code above works as I expected with singular instances and single vectors of the class, but when used on a nested vector the reference address differs from the member address:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    int m;
    int &mref = m;
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    std::cout << (&a.m == &a.mref) << '\n'; // output: 1

    std::vector<A> av1(1);
    std::cout << (&av1[0].m == &av1[0].mref) << '\n'; // output: 1

    std::vector<std::vector<A>> av2(1, std::vector<A>(1));
    std::cout << (&av2[0][0].m == &av2[0][0].mref) << '\n'; // output: 0

    return 0;
}
```

I thought reference variables acted as aliases of their assigned variable and were resolved at compile time without being assigned any actual memory at runtime, unlike pointers. Why is this not consistent with the behavior displayed above? What would be a correct way to achieve the alias I want?

Comment: another point that would be great to mention despite question answered. that is std::vector does not perform deep copy and therefore you reference remain unchanged so in order to copy reference you can override copy constructor. but keep that in mind most container is std does not perform deep copy. so if you have pointer inside your item you should beware of this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code above works as I expected

Actually it doesn't:

```
class A {
public:
    int m{};
    int &mref = m;
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    A a2 = a;
    std::cout << (&a2.m == &a2.mref) << '\n'; // output: 0
};
```

A reference can be bound only on initialization. Copying will copy the value, not re-bind the reference. So any copy of an object of type `A` will mess up your reference. This is what happens in your nested vector example. You don't need a nested vector to see this. Try and push in a `vector<A>`, the vector will have to resize and during the resize will copy its elements, messing your reference.

> I thought reference variables acted as aliases of their assigned variable ...

True

> ... and were resolved at compile time without being assigned any actual memory at runtime, unlike pointers.

Not always. You cannot always resolve at compile time the reference, in which case the reference will actually be implemented with a pointer behind the scenes.

Possible solutions:

- use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), [the copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%3D) rebinds the reference, but you will need to implement custom copy constructor/assignments for your class:

  ```
  class A {
  public:
      int m{};
      std::reference_wrapper<int> mref = m;

      A() = default;

      A(const A& other) noexcept
          : m{other.m},
            mref{m}
      {}

      A& operator=(const A& other) noexcept
      {
          m = other.m;
          mref = m;

          return *this;
      }
  };
  ```
- use a method that returns a reference to the variable

  ```
  class A {
  public:
      int m{};

      int& mref() { return m; }
      const int& mref() const { return m; }
  };
  ```